# Does AWS Fargate recreate the task in another AZ in the event of AZ failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

As the AWS Fargate tasks are spread across Availability Zones, does the Fargate recreate the task in another AZ in the event of AZ failure or do we need to have manual mechanism to overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

ECS handles that for you but there is a delay in the autoscaling process to be aware of. Let's say you need 50 tasks to serve your users. These tasks are placed in two AZs. As the first AZ becomes unavailable, you only have 25 left to serve your users. The auto scaling process can take some time before 25 new tasks have been provisioned in the remaining AZ. Over-provisioning your tasks could be one way to mitigate the failover time. If you should over-provision, and with how much is up to you and the SLA's of your system. If all this is critical for you, you should simulate an AZ failure to see how that would affect your application and your users.

[Read more in ECS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/capacity-availability.html)